# Inverting 3D viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

In Paint Tool SAI, there's the option to flip the canvas so it's in reverse, which is perfect for when you have angle limitations, such as weak stroke directions. Is there any way this can be replicated with Blender's view?

I'm working on sculpting something but some parts I cannot quite get accurate strokes upon, and my best strokes are going from the upper right to lower left and vice versa, while going from lower right to upper left gives me trouble.

Basically I'm looking for something that inverts the camera view horizontally, but does NOT move the camera itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking through the camera view (not the viewport camera, but the "placed" one), then you can achieve this effect by scaling the camera by -1 on whatever axis you need (X axis demonstrated below):

[image: Flip1]

[image: Flip2]

Comment: Thanks, but can it not be done with the viewport camera?

Comment: As far as I know, the viewport "camera" does not have properties that can be edited like the scene camera (at least without scripting edits), so I think that's the best you can do.

Comment: Oh well. That's at least as close as I"m going to get then, but a temporary camera for use in this certainly helps. Thanks!